# Twitter ADS OAuth1.0 node.js implementation

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, oauth

I am not able to implement how to store `oauth_token`, `oauth_token_secret` after 3rd step, so I can make calls on behalf of user to twitter APIs. I tried using passportjs but no luck.

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-1-0a/obtaining-user-access-tokens

Can anyone help me how I can proceed.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please elaborate on 'I am not able to implement how to store'. Where did you get stuck? What did you try?